# Are ISIN case sensitive?

Tags: programming

Are ISIN codes case sensitive like RIC Codes are?
We need to know this in order to sanitize input.
This completely describes my problem!

Answer (score 4):

ISINs are a 12 character alphanumeric code where the letters allowed are A-Z and the digits are 0-9.

They are not case sensitive.

This is defined in the ISO 6166 standard and the alphabetic characters allowed are given in Annex A of the standard - that is, only A through Z (uppercase) are specified.